# How to solve $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {\frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to solve this limit without using L'Hospital rule?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}}$$

Comment: Hello welcome to SO perhaps we could help you better if you let us know your thought and where you are stuck.

Comment: Might be a good idea to use the binomial expansion, assuming $a > 0$.

Comment: @Mattos How do you know $a \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 If $a$ is not a natural number, then perhaps the generalized binomial theorem is better suited.

Comment: @zz20s If one is prohibited from using LHR, then do you believe that one is allowed to use the GBT?

Comment: @Dr.MV one doesn't know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the generalized binomial expansion, we get
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{-1 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty {a\choose k}x^k }{x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{-1 + 1 + ax + {a\choose 2}x^2 + {a\choose 3}x^3 +\cdots }{x}}$$
$$=a + \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{{a\choose 2}x^2 + {a\choose 3}x^2 +\cdots }{x}}$$
$$=a + \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left[{a\choose 2}x + {a\choose 3}x^2 +\cdots\right]$$
$$=a$$

Note the dependence of $x$ on the entire RHS of the limit in the second-to-last equation

Comment: And how is the generalized binomial theorem obtained?

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't seeing the binomial theorem.

Comment: @Dr.MV If you're Newton? a bit of guessing and handwaving. Formally, proving the GBT is probably harder than just using L'Hopital, but the question had no constraints on this matter

Comment: Yes, apparently so.  My development used only elementary (non-calculus based) analysis.

Answer (score 3):

---

> **PRIMER**:
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm and exponential functions satisfy the inequalities
>
> $$1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x} \tag 1$$
>
> for $x<1$, and
>
> $$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1\tag 2$$
>
> for $x>0$.  We will use the inequalities in $(1)$ and $(2)$ to evaluate the limit of interest.

---

First note that using $(2)$, it is easy to see that for $x>0$ we have

$$\frac{1}{1+x} \le \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\le 1 \tag 3$$

while for $-1<x<0$ we have

$$1 \le \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\le \frac{1}{1+x} \tag 4$$

Applying the squeeze theorem to $(3)$ and $(4)$, we see that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1} \tag 5$$

---

Next, we write $(1+x)^a=e^{a\log(1+x)}$ so that

$$\frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}=\frac{e^{a\log(1+x)}-1}{x}$$

Now, we restrict $x$ such that $a\log(1+x)<1$.  Then, we exploit $(1)$ to reveal

$$\frac{a\log(1+x)}{x}\le \frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}\le \frac{a\log(1+x)}{x(1-a\log(1+x))} \tag 6$$

Using $(5)$ and applying the squeeze theorem to $(6)$, we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}=a}$$

And we are done!  No series, no L'Hospital's, and no derivatives!