# $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x} $

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}  $ I really stuck, because $a$ is not an integer. If it is, I can solve it, but here I totally stuck

Comment: Can you use L'Hôpital?

Comment: Or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789815/how-to-solve-lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac1xa-1x

Answer (score 0):

Using L'hopital you could easily find that: $lim_{x->\infty} \frac{(1+x)^a -1}{x} = lim_{x->\infty} a(1+x)^{a-1}$. Do you think you can answer it from here?

Answer (score 0):

This is the limit of the rate of variation of the function $(1+x)^a$  when $x$ tends to $0$. The limit is the derivative of the function at $x=0$.